# Why is this a maximal torus?

Tags: general-topology

Let $T = \{ \operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta_1},\dots, e^{i\theta_n}): \sum \theta_i = 0 \}$. My book claims that it is an isomorphism by $\operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta_i},\dots, e^{i\theta_n})  \to \operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta_1 - i\theta_n},\dots, e^{i\theta_n - i\theta_{n-1}}).$

Comment: How about writing out the properties an isomorphism needs to satisfy, and then verifying them?

Comment: @AlexR., one can do that, but I want to know how does one come up with such a map in the first place?